# Compression, using invalid data to represent chess board states

Tags: encoding, compression, chess

I am making a chess program and I have been trying to optimize the game board state to use the least amount of data storage possible. I've realized there is a set of data that makes sense (can be decompressed) with my compression algorithm but is also invalid, for example a rook that is eligible for a castling move but is not in its starting position, or a pawn that is not in the fourth/fifth row but is eligible for an En passant move. I am trying to figure out an effective way to have those invalid positions encode a string of 0's between 1 and 61 bits long, to represent empty board spaces.

So given the input either 10110 or 11110 (input might be irrelevant to this problem?) what is a good way to represent between 1 and 61 bits of 0's? Any bits of your choosing can follow so long as it, plus the input, is shorter than the equivalent amount of zero's it would be taking the place of.

This would be used optionally in place of the string of zeros, so for example if there was three 0's it would make more sense to encode it as 000 rather than 10110(your bits here). But if it was say, 16 zeros, then it would be potentially cheaper to encode it as 10110(your bits here). At compression time the decision would be made which to use, and by nature of it at decompression time both would be decompressed to mean the same thing.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding

Comment: @SparkleStep, is this for a real chess program or is it an exercise in data compression? For a real program, optimising for data compression doesn't make much sense...

Comment: @RoadWarrior it is for a real chess program. Because the raw storage for all the possible chess board states exceeds the total amount of storage that exists in the world, I figured storing any real amount of depth in a tree search would benefit from compressed storage.

Comment: @SparkleStep, you don't need to store "any real amount of depth". I would start [here](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Board_Representation) for some ideas on what you need to do.